# Socket can't read large files. Python

Tags: python, sockets

Im doing a project where it connect to a server directory and read all their files.
So i just wrote a code to download the server files whenever i click on it. I can read small size file with no issues, but when i want to view a large content, only 1 line can be view and store to a list. Although i cant read all the large content, but im able to download it with no issues.

**I can read and download all small size content with no issues:**
[image]

**The large file that i want to read from:**
[image]

**Output that i got when i read the large files. (Cant read all the content but i successfully to download the full content file)**
[image]

**CLIENT CODE:**

```
def mouseHover(event):
           x = lbox.curselection()[0]
           file = lbox.get(x)
           ext = (".txt", ".csv")
           if file.endswith(ext):
               self.s.send(("fdown~" + file).encode("utf-8")) #must have
               data = self.s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
               if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
                   filesize = data[6:]
                   self.s.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))
                   f = open(file, 'wb')  # must have
                   data = (self.s.recv(1024))
                   totalRecv = len(data)
                   f.write(data)
                   while int(totalRecv) < int(filesize):
                       data = self.s.recv(1024)
                       totalRecv += len(data)
                       f.write(data)
                       sys.stdout.write("\r|" + "█" * int((totalRecv / float(filesize)) * 50) + "|{0:.2f}".format(
                           (totalRecv / float(filesize)) * 100) + "%  ")
                       sys.stdout.flush()
                       time.sleep(0.01)
                   print("\nDownload Complete!")
                   f.close()

                   global data2
                   data2= data.splitlines()
                   print(data2)
                   self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
                   self.text.insert(tk.END, data)
           else:
               messagebox.showinfo("WARNING", "Currently only .txt/csv file is supported.")


       lbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mouseHover)
```

**SERVER CODE:**

```
# Create a Socket ( connect two computers)
def create_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        host = ""
        port = 9999
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as msg:
        create_socket()


# Binding the socket and listening for connections
def bind_socket():
    try:
        global host
        global port
        global s
        s.bind((host, port))
        s.listen(5)
    except socket.error as msg:
        bind_socket()




# send file list

def flist(conn):
    try:
        arr = pickle.dumps(os.listdir())
        conn.send(arr)
    except:
        conn.send(('Error').encode("utf-8"))



# accept file from server

def fdown(filename, conn):
    try:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
            filesize = data[6:]
            conn.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))
            f = open(filename, 'wb')
            data = (conn.recv(1024))
            totalRecv = len(data)
            f.write(data)
            while int(totalRecv) < int(filesize):
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                totalRecv += len(data)
                f.write(data)
            f.close()
    except:
        conn.send(('Error').encode("utf-8"))


# send file
def fup(filename, conn):
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        conn.send(str.encode("EXISTS " + str(os.path.getsize(filename))))
        filesize = int(os.path.getsize(filename))
        userResponse = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if userResponse[:2] == 'OK':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                conn.send(bytesToSend)
                totalSend = len(bytesToSend)
                while int(totalSend) < int(filesize):
                    bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                    totalSend += len(bytesToSend)
                    conn.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        conn.send("ERROR".encode("utf-8"))




# main
def main(s):
    while True:
        data = (s.recv(1024)).decode("utf-8").split('~')

        if data[0] == 'fdown':
            fup(data[1], s)
        elif data[0] == 'fup':
            fdown(data[1], s)
        elif data[0] == 'flist':
            flist(s)

            break
        else:
            s.send(".".encode('utf-8'))


# Establish connection with a client (socket must be listening)

def socket_accept():
    conn, address = s.accept()
    main(conn)
    conn.close()


create_socket()
bind_socket()
socket_accept()
```

Comment: have you checked whether `filesize` is correct?

Comment: When you do `data2= data.splitlines()` after the loop, `data` is just the last block read from the socket, not the whole file.

Comment: OHH SHEETT, @Barmar i forgot about it hahahha, its working now. tq for reminding

Comment: it store to list properly now, but on the UI text field, its still showing a few line only

Comment: `self.text.insert(tk.END, data)` is just inserting the last block.

Comment: Maybe you should put that in the loop.

Comment: I tried to put the 'insert=data' into the loop. But other files cannot be read or turn into list anymore. Only the large files can be turn into list now.

Comment: What do you mean by turning a file into a list?

Comment: Do you mean `data2`? You should append lines to it each time through the loop, not overwrite it.

Comment: Or concatenate `data` to a string each time through the loop, and then do `data2 = all_data.splitlines()` at the end.

Comment: You could also use `data2 = open(file).read().splitlines()` after you close the file at the end of the loop.

Comment: So many different ways to solve this problem.

Comment: I tried to put the "insert" everything into the loop example: [link](https://ibb.co/jG0HygL). But the result doesnt show anything for other files except the large file example: [link](https://ibb.co/dD9GQzC). [link](https://ibb.co/1XHkJkm)

Comment: You're overwriting `data2` each time through the loop. So it will still just contain the last block when you're done.

Comment: Ohh thanks, it work already. But here come the new issues. Everytime i view the large from UI, it lag as hell hahaha

Comment: It's not inserting into the text box until the whole download is finished. If you want to see it incrementally, you can append each `data` to the text box instead of replace it at the end.

Comment: Ohh got it ! thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you read each block of data, concatenate it to a string containing the whole file. Then at the end of the loop you can split this into lines and display it in the text box.

There's also no need to limit your `recv()` calls to 1000 bytes. Use `filesize - totalRecv` as the limit, and it will receive as much as is available, but not go past the end of the file.

There's no need to convert `filesize` to `int` every time through the loop, do it once when you assign the variable.

```
def mouseHover(event):
    x = lbox.curselection()[0]
    file = lbox.get(x)
    ext = (".txt", ".csv")
    if file.endswith(ext):
        self.s.send(("fdown~" + file).encode("utf-8")) #must have
        data = self.s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
        if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
            filesize = int(data[6:])
            self.s.send("OK".encode("utf-8"))
            all_data = ''
            with open(file, 'wb') as f: # must have
                totalRecv = 0
                while totalRecv < filesize:
                    data = self.s.recv(filesize - totalRecv)
                    totalRecv += len(data)
                    all_data += data
                    f.write(data)
                    sys.stdout.write("\r|" + "█" * int((totalRecv / filesize) * 50) + "|{0:.2f}".format(
                            (totalRecv / filesize) * 100) + "%  ")
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(0.01)
                print("\nDownload Complete!")

            global data2
            data2= all_data.splitlines()
            print(data2)
            self.text.delete('1.0', tk.END)
            self.text.insert(tk.END, all_data)
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("WARNING", "Currently only .txt/csv file is supported.")

lbox.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", mouseHover)
```